# Do Boost.Test's data test cases really require C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++03, boost.test

I work in a specific enterprise environment and there's no C++11 infrastructure at the moment. Recently I started writing unit-tests and decided to utilize Boost.Test framework since Boost is known for its' portability and enterprise-readiness.
While general BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE work great, I found out that dataset tests (BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE) end up including `boost/test/data/monomorphic/fwd.hpp` that includes `<tuple>` unconditionally.
Does DATA_TEST_CASE indeed require C++11? Is there a way to use BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE and utilize Boost's built-in tuples and other shipped libs to comply with C++03 standard?

Comment: Which version of boost? Have you looked at the release notes?

Comment: You should be focussing your efforts on upgrading to C++11 - really, there is no excuse for not doing so. You _will_ have to upgrade at some point, so that point may as well be now - 8 years after the C++11 standard came out.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I disagree. There's no point in upgrading to C++11. They should skip C++11 and upgrade directly to C++17.

Comment: @Jerry No, let's go the whole hog and go for C++20! But seriously, I've been in these "enterprise" environments. and doing any upgrade is a giant political upheaval, which will be opposed on all sides, so you often have to take what you can get. That's not an excuse for doing nothing, however.

Comment: If you can''t upgrade to C++11 or better, Catch2 has a Catch1.x branch which will work  on pre C++11 compilers.

Comment: Boost.Test is compatible with C++03, the data test case feature is not (and wasn't from the first release of that feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost doesn't generally deliberately break c++11 compatibility in existing libraries (though this attitude is changing and you should expect more c++11 requirements in future, see discussions on the boost developer mailing lists).

However new libraries and new features for existing libraries don't adhere to this restriction and generally will require c++11 if that makes the implementation easier/simpler/faster/more reliable etc.

`BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE` was only introduced in boost 1.59.0 so is likely to be using c++11.

The general advice is if using an old compiler use an old version of boost. If you want new features upgrade your compiler and use a recent version of boost.